# How can I keep number and increment in child component with Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

Practicing to make a todo application with Vue JS

Input items save in the localStrage.

**UPDATED**

When you have some added list and reload a page, ID number start from 1(defalut).

Ideal behaviour:

- when reload a page, ID number continues number increment.
- if some items removed, then, add new item, ID number should be the biggest ID number in array(if 8) +1 (should be 9).

My code: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-meninsky-jywtq)

Problem is around here.

**Child2.vue**

```
  created() {
    let keyObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.keyName));

    if (keyObject) {
      this.$emit("update:todos", keyObject);
    } else {
      return;
    }

    if (this.todos.length > 0) {
      console.log(this.todos.id);
      const setId = this.todos.reduce(function(a,b){ return a > b.id ? a : b.id} ,0)
      this.todos.id = setId + 1
      console.log(this.todos.id);

      this.$emit('update:todos', keyObject)
      // this.$emit('update:todos', this.todos.id)
    }
  },
```

Do you know how?

Comment: The problem is `this.todos.push(keyObject);` because it will create a nested array. You need to append the array using concat, or call push on each element of `keyObject` instead. To illustrate, if you had items A, B, C saved, the line will create `[[A, B, C]]` and adding a fourth item you now have `[[A, B, C], D]`. The nesting accumulates each time you reload the app.

Comment: I am not sure what is your goal because you stated 3 different ones

Comment: @Chris G,  thank you for your comment. I'll try to use `concat` to update `todos` array.

Comment: @Billal Begueradj, sorry for the confusion. I'm pretty new to vue, I'm practicing and trying to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid modify props directly using [`.sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier:

App.vue:

```html
<Child2 :todos.sync="todos" :keyName="keyName"/>
```

Child2.vue:

```js
if (keyObject) {
     this.$emit('update:todos', keyObject);
}
```

For get the next id, you can emit this value when you get the array from local storage:

App.vue:

```html
<Child2 :todos.sync="todos" @setTargetId="setTargetId" :keyName="keyName"/>
```

```js
methods: {
    // ...
    setTargetId(newTargetId){
        this.$set(this.target, 'id', newTargetId );
    }
}
```

Child2.vue:

```js
// ...
created() {
    let keyObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.keyName));

    // Check keyObject 
    if (keyObject) {
        // update todo on App.vue
        this.$emit("update:todos", keyObject);

        // set target.id
        const setId = keyObject.reduce(function(a,b){ return a > b.id ? a : b.id} ,0)
        this.$emit('setTargetId', setId + 1)
    } 
},
```

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-gates-q7efo

Comment: Thank you very much.
Problem solved.
Now another problem happened.
I'd like to keep ID number increments, when reload page.
Now it restart from `id: 1,` and this cause error.

Is it possible to connect `this.todos.id` by `this.$emit('update:todos', keyObject)` ?
Code updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-meninsky-jywtq

added for `id` increments
`Child2.vue` 
```
if (this.todos.length > 0) {..here..}
```

Comment: You can emit an event when get the array, I update my answer and the codesandbox link

Comment: just saw your code. never seen `$set` but now I know how to use.
thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

There is inconsistent formatting in keyObject and this.todos( this.todos is actually nested), and you are not suppose to mutate props.

ALSO NOTICE THE ID INCREMENTATION TO AVOID DUPLICATE ERROR IN LOOPS

My suggestion App.vue:

```
methods: {
    addBtn() {

      const todo = { id: this.target.id, name: this.target.name, done: false };
      this.todos.push(todo);
      localStorage.setItem(this.keyName, JSON.stringify(this.todos));
      this.target.name = "";
      //it is important to increment the id based on current length
      this.target.id = this.todos.length + 1;
    },
    onInputChange(val) {
      this.target.name = val;
    }
  },
  created() {
     let todosObject  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.keyName));
     if(todosObject){
       this.todos = todosObject
       //again base the id on the current length, to avoid duplicate error in loops later 
       this.target.id = this.todos.length+1
     }

  }
```

Child2:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
        ID: {{ todo.id }} / Name: {{ todo.name }}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="todo.done"
          @click="status(todo)"
        >
        <button @click="removeBtn(todo)">Remove item</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    todos: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    keyName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    removeBtn(item) {
      const index = this.todos.indexOf(item);
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      localStorage.setItem(this.keyName, JSON.stringify(this.todos));
      if (this.todos.length === 0) {
        console.log("no item");
      }
    },
    status(todo) {
      todo.done = !todo.done;
      localStorage.setItem(this.keyName, JSON.stringify(this.todos));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
and thanks for the notion.
I actualy have trouble on it.
`this.target.id = this.todos.length+1` is not enough in my case.
when remove some items, and reload a page, biggest `id` number and `todos.length` are not always the same. in this case, if new item added, error occured. i'd like to increment based on biggest `target.id`. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, my code does that, see the created() section in App.vue, when refreshed it always get the current length from localStorage and increment it by 1

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your problem, you want to update the value of the props from a child component.

To do that you might want to emit the change from a child component back to the parent.

Below is one way of doing that:

In your child component:

```
this.todosArray = this.todosArray.concat(keyObject); //concat with an existing array
this.$emit("updateTodos", this.todosArray); //emit new array back to parent
```

In your parent component, where u register your child component:

```
<Child2 :todos="todos" :keyName="keyName" @updateTodos="updateTodos"/>
```

and then add a method to update the original array with the value that will come from the child component.

```
updateTodos(value) {
 this.todos = value
}
```

I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much. i've never used `concat` but now I know how to use it :)