# How to use local storage in making a todo list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**JS code**

```
var response = document.querySelector('#name').value;
localStorage.getItem('li')
localStorage.setItem('li', response)

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;  
  document.querySelector('#name').onkeyup = () => {
    // checking whether the input bar is empty or not
    if (document.querySelector('#name').value.length > 0)
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    else document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
  };

  window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = () => {
      //Crearting a list item
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('id')

      //Appending it to the unordered list
      document.querySelector('.unordered').append(li);

      //Clear input feild
      document.querySelector('#name').value = "";
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

      //Stop form from submitting
      return false;
    };
  };
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Creating new channel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/main.css')}}" />
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'js/button.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'images/Logo.png')}}">
<div class="form-div">
    <form class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Create Channel" autocomplete="off" /><br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Create Channel</button>
    </form>
    <ol class="unordered"></ol>
</div>
{% endblock %}

</html>
```

I am trying to create a todo list and so, for storing the data permanently, even when the browser is shut, i am using local storage. But when i have used local storage in this it isn't working(when i refresh the page, all the contents is erased).In the console when i ran the query localstorage.getItem('li') and then localstorage.setItem('li', response) then it is showing the value entered by the user but is unable to store it permanently. So is my code wrong or there are any logical errors.

Comment: I suggest waiting until the user has clicked submit before trying to store what they typed.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146116/how-can-i-keep-number-and-increment-in-child-component-with-vue-js/

Comment: the .onsubmit function itself means that the button is pressed and than all the code is executed

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `li.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('id')` inside `document.querySelector('form').onsubmit`. So this will be executed only when the form is submitted. To show it normally, you'll have to take it out of this function and put in in `window.load`.

Something like this:

```
    window.onload = () => {


      const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('id') ? 

localStorage.getItem('id') : "";
document.querySelector('.unordered').append(li);

    document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = () => {
      //Crearting a list item
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('id');
      ...
    };
  };
```

Comment: I wrote this code but still on refreshing the  content is going

Comment: What does console.log `localStorage.getItem('id')` print?

Comment: thats actually 'li' and not 'id'. I realized it and, even after changing it the problem still remains the same

Comment: Can you shoe me the whole code now after updation? Also, did you `document.querySelector('.unordered').append(li);` do this after getting the value from localstorage?